# Mega menu dropdown with bootstrap 4

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I try to reproduce  [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Omi236/pen/vZPgjz) , in Bootstrap 4.

The following [Codepen](https://codepen.io/dujp/pen/bYLdyX/) is where I arrived (drop down with 2 columns), helping my tutorials on the net.

Navbar HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar navbar-dark bg-primary">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown"
        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown has-mega-menu">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
                    aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>

                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <div class="px-0 container container-sm">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6 col-md-x">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Or a link</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6 col-md-x">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Or a link</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Or a link</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
@media screen and (min-width: 576px) {
  .has-mega-menu .container-sm {
    width: 540px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .has-mega-menu .container-md {
    width: 720px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .has-mega-menu .container-lg {
    width: 960px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .has-mega-menu .container-xl {
    width: 1140px;
  }
}
```

I have two problems:

- This design is not responsive (the two columns of the dropdown should
  be placed under each other on small screens)
- I would like the megamenu to occupy the full width of the navbar, as
  on the BS3 example, and be responsive

Comment: To make it occupy the whole width, remove the outer container. (or change the class to `container-fluid`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `position:static` to the `<li>` that's above the dropdown menu. This will make your dropdown menu go full width. And then to get it to collapse properly, change the `.col-6` that you are using in the dropdown to be `.col-md-6` and that should fix it.

Comment: **position-static** to the **li** is a good start. Then add **width:100%** to **dropdown-menu** rule one of the problems. The css is no longer useful. Replacing col-6 or col-4 by **col** sets the other problem: the menu becomes responsive.

Answer (score 0):

you should change your

`<div class="col-6 col-md-x">`

to

`<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-x">`

so that they work for the menus and then check again

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 576px) {
  .has-mega-menu .container-sm {
    width: 540px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .has-mega-menu .container-md {
    width: 720px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .has-mega-menu .container-lg {
    width: 960px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .has-mega-menu .container-xl {
    width: 1140px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar navbar-dark bg-primary">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown has-mega-menu">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>

          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <div class="px-0 container container-sm">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-x">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Or a link</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-x">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Or a link</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Or a link</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```